# Casting Pointer & getting Warnings

Tags: c, pointers

I'm using a function pointer in some code, and it's working, but throwing a warning. I'm learning C and I'd like to understand why.

Here's the parent function that contains the function pointer:

```
void    drag_perform64(t_drag *x, double **ins, double **outs, long sampleframes, void (*voicemode)(void *, t_double, t_double, t_double, t_double)){
//... more code here
voicemode(x, this_lo, this_hi, grad, t);
//... more code here
}
```

Here's the declaration for the function I point to

```
void drag_ptr_voicecalc (t_drag *x, t_double lo, t_double hi, t_double grad, t_double t);
```

Here's how I call it:

```
drag_perform64(x, ins, outs, sampleframes, drag_ptr_voicecalc);
```

But I get this error:

```
passing argument 5 of 'drag_perform64' from incompatible pointer type   

expected 'void (*)(void *, t_double,  t_double,  t_double,  t_double)' but argument is of type 'void (*)(struct t_drag *, t_double,  t_double,  t_double,  t_double)'
```

The code works, but I can't get rid of the warning - can anyone advise?

Thanks

Comment: One solution would be to change the prototype/declaration of `drag_ptr_voicecalc` to `void drag_ptr_voicecalc (void *x, t_double lo, t_double hi, t_double grad, t_double t)` (use a `void *`) and then cast the `void *` into a `t_drag *` inside of that function. Another solution would be to change the declaration of `drag_perform64` to `void drag_perform64(t_drag *x, double **ins, double **outs, long sampleframes, void (*voicemode)(t_drag *, t_double, t_double, t_double, t_double))`.

Comment: You declare drag_ptr_voicecalc but you pass drag_shaper_voicecalc

Comment: Excellent - thanks very much! If you paste that in as an answer I'll mark it as the right answer. I'd thought it was legal to cast any pointer to void, but I guess not. I'll go back to the textbooks.

Comment: thanks stark - I actually pass any one of several functions, but I mistakenly picked two different ones for this example. I'll change my question - thanks for the spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Copied and pasted from comments)

One solution would be to change the prototype/declaration of `drag_ptr_voicecalc` to

```
void drag_ptr_voicecalc (void *x, t_double lo, t_double hi, t_double grad, t_double t)
```

(use a `void *`) and then cast the `void *` into a `t_drag *` inside of that function.

Another solution would be to change the declaration of drag_perform64 to

```
void drag_perform64(t_drag *x, double **ins, double **outs, long sampleframes, void (*voicemode)(t_drag *, t_double, t_double, t_double, t_double)).
```

Answer (score 1):

Your headline is wrong. You are not casting a pointer to struct to a void*. You are casting one function pointer type to an incompatible pointer function type.

If you call drag_perform64, it expects a t_drag* as its first parameter, and the caller passes a t_drag* as the first parameter. If you call drag_perform64 through a function pointer with the wrong type, it still expects a t_drag* as the first parameter, but the caller will put a void* there. The problem is that no cast happens. In C and C++, different pointer types can have different sizes and different values. You could have implementations where a void* is 64 bit and a t_drag* is 32 bit. You can imagine that things will go wrong in that situation.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have altered the headline to avoid confusing people.